# Upgrading Visual Studio Project from 2010 to 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2017, designer

I have an older project that was written in VS 2010 a few years back, and now I need to make some changes to it. I'm personally working in VS 2017, and for some reason, every item in the designer needs to be resized and realigned. Is this common? Because my coworker opened it in VS 2013 and it looked fine.

Comment: Have you tried unloading and reloading the project? I think vs 2017 csproject files have changed a little bit. The only reason i say that, is that I had some issues with an older project and it loaded fine once I had unloaded/reloaded.